# Is it possible that dotdotdot removes my text?

Tags: jquery, dotdotdot

I have a `h4`:

```
<h4 class="ddd" style="word-wrap: break-word;">Simple text</h4>
```

and on document.ready:

```
jQuery(".ddd").dotdotdot({});
```

in my browswer the text is gone, the inspector shows `<h4 class="ddd" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></h4>`

BUT when I open the source of it, the text "`Simple text`" is still there! Is it possible that `dotdotdot` hides my text?

Comment: well, as you've notices: Yes.

Comment: If you want ellipsis if a text is too long, just use `text-overflow:ellipsis;` etc.

Comment: Source shows you the original state of the document before js kicks in.  Inspecting shows you the current state of the document including any changes js has made so something is removing your text - most likely the dot plugin (but without seeing all your code that replicates the error, I cannot say for certain)

Comment: but I thought its not possible that dotdotdot even disappears that text...